# Change SQLite columns type from INTEGER to BLOB in existing table with data

Tags: c++, sqlite

I use SQLite database (or `sqlite3` class) in my software written in C++. In the new version of software I need to change data type on several columns in an existing table from `INTEGER` to `BLOB`.

Is there an easy way to do this programmatically?

Do I really need to recreate the table? The reason I hesitate to do so is because the table also has an index associated with it, and also is referenced by other tables attaching them to it.

Comment: SQLite [does not have fixed column types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). How exactly do you want to change the values in the column?

Comment: @CL.: In the old version I would add data as `UPDATE tbl SET col=23` or by using a 64-bit integer, but now I'll be doing `UPDATE tbl SET col=x'ab094587ae387a00118234'` or in other words it will have a longer byte array stored in it.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not have any mechanism to change columns; you have to recreate the table.

Indexes and foreign keys do not prevent you from doing this (if you have actual foreign key constraints, you can disable checking them with [PRAGMA foreign_keys](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys)).

Due to SQLite's [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), you do not actually have to change the table definition.

Comment: So what you're saying is that instead of writing 8-byte integers into a column I can starting writing arbitrary length byte blobs into it without changing the column type. Am I reading it correctly?